# Convert select dropdown into list for printing

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert <select> dropdown into an unordered list using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery)

I want to convert all select dropdowns into ul lists for printing.

```
<select>
 <option>Item 1</option>
 <option>Item 2</option>
 <option>Item 3</option>
</select>
```

into:

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Why does this only show?:

```
<ul></ul>
```

jquery:

```
$('select').parent().append('<ul></ul>');
$('select option').each(function(){
  $('<ul>').append('<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>');
});

$('select').remove();
```

edit: removed select ID. I want to step through each  and not just one particular select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `ul` element at every step in the loop. Use this instead:

```
var $select = $('#oberservationType'),
    $list = $('<ul />');

$select.find('option').each(function(){
    $list.append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
});

$select.after( $list ).remove();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDbgv/

---

To do this for every `select` on the page, use this:

```
$('select').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $list = $('<ul />');

    $this.find('option').each(function(){
        $list.append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
    });

    $this.after( $list ).remove();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDbgv/2/

Comment: I would like it to go through all select and not just #oberservationType. How would I step through each <select> for the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

This should do. Please give it a try once.

```
$(function()
{
    var items = $('#oberservationType option'), str = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        str = str + '<li>'+items[i].innerHTML+'</li>';
    }
    str = str + '</ul>';
    console.log(str);
    $('<div/>').html(str).appendTo('body');
    $('#oberservationType').remove();

});
```