# How to move option list items to <ul> using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I humbly ask anyone because I'm having trouble moving this (option list items):

```
<select class="list-of-users">
<option class="list-of-users">Sample Group</option>
<option class="list-of-users">TOP Group</option>
<option class="list-of-users">TEST Group</option>
<option class="list-of-users">AWD Group</option>
</select>
```

to this list:

```
<ul class="list-of-members">
<li class="list-of-members"></li>
<li class="list-of-members"></li>
<li class="list-of-members"></li>
<li class="list-of-members"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm running in circles up until now. Thank you in advance..

Comment: what do you mean by 'moving'? do you want a select block appended to the ul or do you want the text from each option created as a new li

Comment: Edit the question and add your code you have tried to achieve that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert <select> dropdown into an unordered list using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:  **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBn3r/)**

```
var ul = $("<ul/>").addClass("list-of-members");
$('body').append(ul);
$('.list-of-users option').each(function () {
    $('ul').append($("<li/>").text($(this).text()).addClass("list-of-members"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.list-of-users').on('change',function(){
  var value = $(this);

  $('ul.list-of-members').append('<li class="list-of-members">'+value.val()+'</li>')

});
```

if this is not what you want the see below link

[How to convert <select> dropdown into an unordered list using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ul = $("<ul/>").addClass("list-of-members");
$("option.list-of-users").each(function(){
   ul.append($("<li/>").html($(this).html()).addClass("list-of-members"));
});
$(".list-of-users").replaceWith(ul);
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z3uU3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vDY97/)**

```
strToAppend = "";
$('option.list-of-users').each(function () {
    strToAppend += "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
});

$('ul.list-of-members').append(strToAppend);
```