# Change Select List Option background colour on hover in html

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the default background color of the select list option on hover?

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

```css
select {
    -webkit-border-radius:25px; -moz-border-radius:25px; border-radius:25px;
}

select:hover {    
    background-color:gren;
}

option:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}

option {
    -webkit-border-radius:25px; -moz-border-radius:25px; border-radius:25px;
    color:blue;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

I have tried option `:hover{background-color:red;}`, but it is of no use. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Currently there is no way to apply a css to get your desired result . Why not use libraries like [choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) . These allow you to style the way you want.

If you don want to use third party libraries then you can make a simple un-ordered list and play with some css.Here is thread you could follow

[How to convert <select> dropdown into an unordered list using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.

It's really, if not use native selects, if you create custom select widget from html elements, t.e. "li".