# How to change the default highlight color of drop down in html from blue to some other color for <select><option> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

How to change the default highlight color of drop down in HTML from blue to some other color for `<select><option>` tags, using some CSS properties or from Javascript?

The requirement is I have to use the `<select> <option>` tags only. I tried the code below, but it didn't work for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dropdown Colour</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            option:hover {
                background:#C6C4BD;
            }
        </style>    
    </head>

    <body>

        <select>
            <option>Shell</option>
            <option>Cabbage</option>
            <option>Beans</option>
            <option>Cheese</option>
            <option>Clock</option>
            <option>Monkey</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

try setting outline and/or border properties of select.

```
select{outline:1px solid green;border:1px solid black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way I know of that this can be accomplished using only CSS.

However, using jQuery I was able to achieve a similar effect.

[<kbd>***Live Demo***</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/SpWwa/)

Your dropdown changes because i have to set the size of the select element which makes it look like a list-box. Maybe somebody can improvise on this.

Here is the jQuery i used

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {   
    $('select').on('mouseenter', 'option', function (e) {
        this.style.background = "limegreen";
    });
    $('select').on('mouseleave', 'option', function (e) {
        this.style.background = "none";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this, hope it may help you

```
     select option{
        background: red;
        color: #fff;
        outline:1px solid green;
       }
```