# CSS - Select box, how to change text color with the selected option

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this select input:

```
<select name="color_tarea" id="color_tarea" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" class="form-control">
    <option value="danger" class="text-danger">&#xf111; Máxima prioridade</option>
    <option value="warning" class="text-warning">&#xf111; Prioridade elevada</option>
    <option value="info" class="text-info">&#xf111; Información</option>
    <option value="primary" class="text-primary">&#xf111; Pouco importante</option>
    <option value="success" class="text-success">&#xf111; Cando se poda</option>
</select>
```

Every option has his own text color. Now I want to change the main color (selected option) with the color selected. I can't find a way with only CSS, how can I get the class of the selected option for changing it with jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
The question marked as possible solution is not my solution. That is for changing the placeholder (text of an input when is no text written). I need the text on the main select box (not an option) changes with the color of the chosen option. I wonder this explains correctly the situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a select dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answers, but is a little more complicated. I edited to better explain what I need to  achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very easy with CSS only. **Here are some options**:

---

### Changing the style of the selected element (CSS only):

```css
option:checked {
  color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<select name="color_tarea" id="color_tarea" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" class="form-control">
    <option value="danger" class="text-danger">&#xf111; Máxima prioridade</option>
    <option value="warning" class="text-warning">&#xf111; Prioridade elevada</option>
    <option value="info" class="text-info">&#xf111; Información</option>
    <option value="primary" class="text-primary">&#xf111; Pouco importante</option>
    <option value="success" class="text-success">&#xf111; Cando se poda</option>
</select>
```

---

### Change the style of the item on hover:

unfortunately I haven't managed to make it work with CSS only, and it only works on `size="2"` or higher (i.e. not 1). This runs on jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function (event) {   
    $('select').on('mouseenter', 'option', function (e) {
        this.style.color = "limegreen";
    });
    $('select').on('mouseleave', 'option', function (e) {
        this.style.color = "black";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="5" name="color_tarea" id="color_tarea" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;" class="form-control">
    <option value="danger" class="text-danger">&#xf111; Máxima prioridade</option>
    <option value="warning" class="text-warning">&#xf111; Prioridade elevada</option>
    <option value="info" class="text-info">&#xf111; Información</option>
    <option value="primary" class="text-primary">&#xf111; Pouco importante</option>
    <option value="success" class="text-success">&#xf111; Cando se poda</option>
</select>
```

Alas, the CSS only solution doesn't work when you make the `size` attribute higher than 1.

---

### Alternatives:

You can use a library like [this one](http://%20Based%20my%20answer%20on%20[this][1]%20and%20some%20research.). Or you could build your own dropdown with a good old ul>li setup.

Based my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289723/how-to-change-the-default-highlight-color-of-drop-down-in-html-from-blue-to-some) and some research. That's as much as I can do, best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I guess I did a bad explanation. In my HTML I have 5 options with one different color each. What I need is not the options highlighted or even changed the color, I need to change main select box as is seen depending on the element selected (is a bit difficult to explain, sorry).

Comment: I'll look at it later. I think I get what you mean.