# How to change browser's default hover background-color?

Tags: css

I have used following solutions..

```
select:hover {
color: #444645;
background: #ddd;
}
```

And

```
select option:hover {
color: #444645;
background: #ddd;
}
```

But it didn't work.
Please help me with your solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add your remaining codes.

Comment: Are you trying to change the default hover color for form select option elements? ... You can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html

Answer (score 1):

The style of a `select` component is browser AND OS specific. So it's different across Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc. AND Windows and Mac.

**I'm afraid you can't style the dropdown.**

You can style the select box [as shown here](https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx), but the dropdown is a no go.

If you really want a custom dropdown, I'm afraid you'll have to resort to using javascript.
[Here's a basic tutorial on creating one.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate some more on the context? Maybe provide the html file you were working on?

Right now you are adding behavior to a `<select>` element. If it is the page's background you are trying to change, you will need to target the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Well, i am working on GWT and here i have a global external .css file.
I know how to use this css file for styling, but i really don't know how to use
this <select> element.

Comment: If GWT comes with its own stylesheet(s), you should add that to the question, because this is information vital to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first one works at least Chrome and Firefox

```
select:hover {
color: #444645;
background: #ddd;
}
```

Try it at:

https://codepen.io/pekechis/pen/LyNMea