# Styling Bootstrap Select Dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've tried all sorts of ways, many mentioned on Stackoverflow but have been unable to resolve this.

I'm trying to remove or replace some styles on the bootstrap select box I keep having trouble styling the placeholder and background text on the selected Item.

Specifically I want to turn off all the blue in the image below and set the placeholder to black with white color.

[image]

I also want to get rid of the blue in this picture.
[image]

I think that it has something to do with Bootstrap styling things in JavaScript and overriding anything I do.

Comment: I think you're going to need a plugin to achieve this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html

Comment: post the code you have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try bootstrap-select. here is https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ try below snippet.

Bootstrap-select works in all bootstrap css version

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```