# How to change background color blue to grey for SELECT <OPTION> tag specifically when mouse hovers on options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was able to achieve this by adding `size`, however if I remove this it wont show any longer. Thank you in advance.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <select class="star" att="0" size="2">
    <option>Shell</option>
    <option>Cabbage</option>
    <option>Beans</option>
    <option>Cheese</option>
    <option>Clock</option>
    <option>Monkey</option>
  </select>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(event) {
      $('select').on('mouseenter', 'option', function(e) {
        this.style.background = "#DCDCDC";
      });
      $('select').on('mouseleave', 'option', function(e) {
        this.style.background = "none";
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the HTML and CSS of the code? So we can help you better?

Comment: <select name="mySelect" class="select-min">
   <option value="0">please select</option>
   <option value="1">item1</option>
   <option value="2">item2</option>
   <option value="3">item3</option>
   <option value="4">item4</option>
   <option value="5">item5</option>
</select>
Thank you Independent!! 

<script> $(document).ready(function (event) {   
    $('select').on('mouseenter', 'option', function (e) {
        this.style.background = "#DCDCDC";
    });
    $('select').on('mouseleave', 'option', function (e) {
        this.style.background = "none";
    });
});</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this with css

```css
.star option {
    background-color: blue;
}
.star option:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<select class="star" att="0" size="2">
    <option>Shell</option>
    <option>Cabbage</option>
    <option>Beans</option>
    <option>Cheese</option>
    <option>Clock</option>
    <option>Monkey</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt. tried but was unsuccessful not getting the desired output. by default it displays blue color on options but I want to achieve grey color when I hover on options

Comment: @Revanth Yeah. Thats what `.star option:hover` is for

Comment: Change the default background-color to "transparent" and voilá! The selected one will remain blue, but grey on hover.

Comment: @Revanth I just edited my answer to be a snippet so you see what i mean.

Comment: I see it, but maybe he doesn't want the rest of the elements to have a blue background.

Comment: @IndPendent Possible. But he said they are blue in the title of the question. This is just an example color to show that it works.

Comment: OP also says in the question that they want to make the background blue by adding size=2... so who knows what the OP actually wants?

Comment: Thank you @Matt I was able to achieve it with size but i am looking for it to change without size option being passed. When I remove size it stopped working.

Comment: @Revanth Ok. I just loocked into this. It doesnt seem to be possible to do that with the default `<select>`. However it can be done by creating a dropdown out of different `HTML` elements. Lists for example.

Comment: This might help you out to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html

Answer (score 0):

this is browser specific gui, maybe try look into jquery UI to replace whole element into div element , and select box will be set to invisible;