# remove blue background on hover of select option

Tags: html, css

How can I change background color of select option tag which is blue by default.I am trying to remove background also but its not working out

```css
select option:hover{
background:none;
}
```

```html
 <select class="select">
       <option value="BI"> BI</option>
       <option value="BI2"> BI</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Select List Option background colour on hover in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html)

Comment: Refer to this question answers: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown/19388345#:~:text=To%20both%20style%20the%20hover,to%20the%20menu%20background%20color.**