# Change selection color in scroll-list

Tags: html, css, list, colors

How do I change the selection color in this simple listbox?
(its always blue :( )

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/pr6tvsxm/7/)

```
<select name="fruit" size="4" multiple>
    <option selected>Apples</option>
    <option>Bananas</option>                                                             
    <option>Oranges</option> 
    <option>Watermelon</option>
    <option>Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please close your tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing <select> highlight color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667086/changing-select-highlight-color)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to apply a css to get the result you are looking for.

You can make a simple un-ordered list and play with some css, then... Here is thread for that:

[How to convert <select> dropdown into an unordered list using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery)