# Changing default selection list 'blue' background to a different color

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the default blue color of a selector list.

Here's an image illustrating what I'm talking about: 
[image]

Where the S is highlighted, is it possible to change that background color (the color of the selected size only) to something else? I tried using

```
 select:active {
   background-color:#abd5cd;
 }
```

But that only shows the color when you actually click on the selector box.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Duplicated I think, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Change the dropdown into an unordered list using jQuery as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery)

Option 2: Using [select2](http://select2.github.io/) or [choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to modify the list with jQuery.

I don't believe that it can be modified directly with CSS.