# CSS drop down menu list color does not change on hover in Google chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problem with CSS drop down menu which does not work in chrome on hover.

**Expected Behavior:** Hovering on any of list item should change the background color to what is set using CSS rules.

**Actual behavior:** Default color(blue) stays even after hovering on list item.

If i run the same code in Internet Explorer(IE 10,11) it is working absolutely fine but not in chrome.My chrome version is 47.

MyCode:

```css
 <style> option:hover {
   background: #01A982;
 }
 </style>
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

**JsFiddle Link :** https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepb/p7jz9g95/

Comment: Where is code? post your sample code here

Comment: post your code or add a fiddle

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't support `:hover` on option elements. There isn't really a simple workaround for this. You would need to use a javascript solution or some other type of elements that are made to look & act like a select, if you really need `:hover` support in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Since select and option tags make some trouble with styling them, maybe changing your select/options elements to a list element will help you:

[Convert select dropdown into unordered list with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery)