# How can I remove the hover colour from html select object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a simple colour picker using html/css with just four colours - so far so good.

What's annoying me is that when you hover over an option in the dropdown, it changes to blue because of the hover state - but I can't seem to disable this in the css.

I've tried the `select:hover` and `option:hover` properties but nothing seems to work. Is there an alternative to this without using a library that will achieve the same effect?

```js
function changeColor() {
 var c = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundColor = c;  
}

document.getElementById("colourPicker").addEventListener("change", changeColor);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#colourPicker {
  width: 50px;  
}

#result {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.amber {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

.green {
  background-color: #00b300;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
Pick a colour:
<select id="colourPicker">
  <option value="#ffffff" class="white"></option>
  <option value="#ff0000" class="red"></option>
  <option value="#ffa500" class="amber"></option>
  <option value="#00b300" class="green"></option>
</select>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="result">
<center>Result Colour</center>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can change the behavior of the native dropdown with CSS. You should replace it with HTML elements, perhaps using a plugin like Select2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740391/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover-in-html)

Comment: Don't do that. Please. Don't. On mobile, all you get is blank options with no indication of what they mean at all. Just use `<input type="color" />`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I need to restrict the colour options to just these 4 though, which I don't believe is possible with the html5 input type? Also is it cross-browser compatible?

Comment: In that case, I would suggest radio buttons. These will be much easier to style. (But in general, yes, `<input type="color" />` is supported by all modern browsers)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol not a bad suggestion, and would be more UX friendly - I'll give it a whirl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the problems you are already facing, your current design falls apart entirely when viewed on mobile. Mobile devices generally present a special UI overlay featuring the available options and a radio button for each, and in this case it's just four blank options.

Consider instead using... radio buttons! You can use labels to show off the colour options. For example...

```css
.colourchoices>label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<p class="colourchoices">
  <label style="background-color:#ffffff">
    <input type="radio" value="#ffffff" name="col" />White
  </label>
  <label style="background-color:#ff0000;color:white">
    <input type="radio" value="#ff0000" name="col" /> Red
  </label>
  <label style="background-color:#ffa500;color:white">
    <input type="radio" value="#ffa500" name="col" /> Amber
  </label>
  <label style="background-color:#00b300;color:white">
    <input type="radio" value="#00b300" name="col" /> Green
  </label>
</p>
```

Notice how this gives you as much freedom as you like with regards to styling the elements.

Comment: This is simple and effective which is the kind of alternative I was hoping for. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently style the options in a drop down. The best option you have is to use an un-ordered list and some CSS magic. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336437/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-into-an-unordered-list-using-jquery) out

Comment: i'm going to take a slightly different approach, but this essentially answers my question in that it isn't possible.

Comment: there's always more than one way to skin a cat :) You could use a library, as others have suggested. But yeah, it can't be styled at the moment. Each browser renders them their own way...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using a library for something so trivial, but indeed there is always more than one way... :)